# Explanation of all right cosets being in one-to-one correspondence for a finite group & subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working--slowly--through Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*, and I've hit on a lemma that I'm having trouble visualizing: *There is a 1-1 correspondence between any two right cosets of H in G* (2.7, p. 35 my edition).

It's easy for me to make sense of this in the case of an infinite *G*, as it's describing modular arithmetic.

However, I'm having trouble visualizing an example where this would hold with finite *H* and *G*.

It would seem possible to create a subgroup *H* that was, in other ways, a valid subgroup, but which did not have a number of members divisible by the number of members in the group *G* (e.g. a subgroup with three members in a group with ten)

Can someone help me make more sense of what's going on here?

Comment: It's saying, in effect, that every coset of $H$ has the same number of elements as $H$.

Comment: This is nothing like modular arithmetic in general for infinite groups.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Could you clarify what you mean? My understanding is that if you have an infinite subgroup *H*, e.g. {...,-12, -8, -4, 0, 4, 8, 12,...} Your cosets in *G* will be {...,-13, -9, -5, -1, 3, 7, 11, ...}, {...-14, -10, -6, -2, 2, 6, 10,...}, etc. And in this case there is a 1:1 relationship between each coset and *H*, and that the members of each coset are an equivalence class. The intersection of *H* and its cosets is a null set, and the union of *H* and its cosets is *G*. This seems to describe the underlying structure of modular arithmetic.

Comment: But the integers is not the only infinite group. Sure, if $G = \mathbb{Z}$ then you get modular arithmetic.

Comment: Actually, this is extremely misleading, since in this case, every collection of cosets is a group, since all subgroups are normal in an abelian group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks for the clarification. That was indeed where I was coming from. Herstein makes the relationship explicit a few paragraphs earlier--Sorry I wasn't more exact in my original question. I'll have to blame it on my degree in the humanities. :D

Comment: @AndresMejia I don't follow that. What do you mean by a collection of cosets being a group in this case?

Comment: I mean that in general, one considers left cosets, but these cases are "modular arithmetic" because when the group is normal, the collection of left/right cosets inherit a natural group structure. I just think this image makes cosets seem much more like "modular arithmetic" than they should. I guess I'm being unclear, so I'll stop speaking now :).

Comment: @AndresMejia, it seems like a good entry point if you're someone like me, and you have a hard time imagining specific examples. :D